# IIS rewrite rules skipped even though the pattern matches

Tags: iis, redirect, url-rewriting

Sorry for the vague title, the problem is too complex to summarize in a short phrase...

I'm trying to set up the following redirection rules:

1. `blog.mydomain.net/en/something`: redirected to `www.mydomain.com/something`
2. `blog.mydomain.net/fr/something`: redirected to `www.mydomain.fr/something`
3. `blog.mydomain.net/*`: redirected to `www.mydomain.com`

Rule 3 is working, but rules 1 and 2 seem to be skipped so rule 3 is always applied. Here are my web.config rules:

```xml
<!-- Canonicalize mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com -->
<rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule_en" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>

<!-- Canonicalize mydomain.fr to www.mydomain.fr -->
<rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule_fr" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain\.fr$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.fr/{R:1}" />
</rule>

<!-- Redirect blog.mydomain.net/en/something to www.mydomain.com/something -->
<rule name="RedirectBlog_en" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^/en(/.*)?$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^blog\.mydomain\.net$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
<!-- Redirect blog.mydomain.net/fr/something to www.mydomain.fr/something -->
<rule name="RedirectBlog_fr" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^/fr(/.*)?$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^blog\.mydomain\.net$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.fr/{R:1}" />
</rule>

<!-- Redirect blog.mydomain.net/* to www.mydomain.com -->
<rule name="RedirectBlog_other" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^blog\.mydomain\.net$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com/" />
</rule>

<!-- Wordpress-specific rules -->
...
```

I don't understand why rules `RedirectBlog_en` and `RedirectBlog_fr` are skipped; I tested the regular expressions and they work fine.

Can anyone spot the problem?

---

EDIT: if I disable the 3rd rule (RedirectBlog_other), then rules 1 and 2 work fine... how is it possible, since rules 1 and 2 are executed before rule 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it!

First, things weren't happening as I thought; rules 1 and 2 were *not* working when I disabled rule 3: I was still redirected to my actual domain, but this was done by Wordpress, not by my rules.

Second, my pattern for matching the URL was wrong: the leading '/' is *not* included in the input, so my rules weren't matching at all.